# How to redirect all not found page to an error page

Tags: .htaccess, custom-error-pages

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC] 
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /news.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /category.php?kategori=$1 [NC,L]
```

on my .htaccess document

It is working and redirecting to the error page the page when i type [www.example.com/hdjskahdjska](http://www.example.com/hdjskahdjska)

But when i typed [www.example.com/news.phpdsadsadsa](http://www.example.com/news.phpdsadsadsa) it doesn't redirect to the error page, but it shown me a multiple choice page whether to choose news.php or news.html

And when i typed  [www.example.com/news/dsadsadsa](http://www.example.com/news/dsadsadsa) it shown my page news without any content on it, how can i also redirect that url to an error page ?

I also want when someone typed [www.example.com/index.php](http://www.example.com/index.php) or [www.example.com/index.html](http://www.example.com/index.html) to redirect to the error page.

I need your help please Thank you

Comment: Could you please do let us know if you have any other rules apart from these mentioned ones in your htaccess rules file?

Comment: no i don't have any other rules sir